# Silverlight Multipage Printing

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, printing

I am implementing silverlight printing using `PrintDocument`. My UI is generated runtime using `XamlReader` which parse `xaml` which I have stored in db.

Here is code:

```
                        string str = sb.ToString();
                        newUI = XamlReader.Load(sb.ToString()) as FrameworkElement;
                        newUI.DataContext = ReportData;
                        grdPreviewArea.Children.Add(newUI);
                        grdPreviewArea.Height = pageHeight;
                        grdPreviewArea.Width = pageWidth;
                        Grid.SetColumn(newUI, 1);
                        Grid.SetRow(newUI, 1);
```

Now to print I am setting `newUI` as `e.PageVisual` in my print event handle.
This works fine if rendered UI is fits single page , but I am not able to print second page if it does not fits single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to work out how many pages are needed

  Dim pagesNeeded As Integer = Math.Ceiling(gridHeight / pageHeight) //gets number of pages needed
- Then once the first page has been sent to the printer, you need to move that data out of view and bring the new data into view ready to print. I do this by converting the whole dataset into an image/UI element, i can then adjust Y value accordingly to bring the next set of required data on screen.

  transformGroup.Children.Add(New TranslateTransform() With {.Y = -(pageIndex * `pageHeight)})`
- Then once the number of needed pages is reached, tell the printer to stop

  ```
      If pagesLeft <= 0 Then
          e.HasMorePages = False
          Exit Sub
      Else
          e.HasMorePages = True
      End If
  ```

Or if this is too much work, you can simply just scale all the notes to fit onto screen. Again probably by converting to UI element.

Check out this link for converting to a UI element.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/248553/Silverlight-converting-to-image-and-printing-an-UI

Hope this helps